# Why Unit Testing Assert.AreEqual() method does NOT pick up my own Equals() method in the customized class

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I am trying to build a Unit Test project for a.Net Framework Class Library project.  I have some customized model types, which implement the `IEquatable<T>` interface and have their own `Equals()` method,  in the project to be tested. 
I read several docs online where they say the `Assert.AreEqual` method only operates `RefereceEqual` when the object does not have its own `Equals()` method. But I found that the TestMethod still not return true even the object has its own `Equals` method. I recreated the scenario below using a simple example. Did I do something wrong?

```
namespace Demo
{
    public class MyDog : IEquatable<MyDog>
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Age;

        public bool Equals(MyDog other)
        {
            if (other == null) return false;
            return (this.Name == other.Name) && (this.Age == other.Age);
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace DemoTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void MyDogTest()
        {
            var dog1 = new MyDog { Age = 10, Name = "Jack" };
            var dog2 = new MyDog { Age = 10, Name = "Jack" };

            Assert.AreEqual(dog1, dog2);
        }
    }
}
```

the `dog1.Equals(dog2)` will return true, while the unit test will fail. How to properly compare dog1 and dog2 in the Test method.

Comment: This note should answer your question https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netframework-4.8#notes-to-implementers

Comment: `Assert.AreEqual` is using the other `Equals(object)` from base object

Comment: Try using `Assert.IsTrue( dog1.equals(dog2) )`

Comment: And here is a good example to learn from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1.equals?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @Nkosi Appreciate sir! Good refer

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood, the Assert.AreEqual method uses object.Equals to compare those two objects. so if you update the code to something like

```
     public class MyDog
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Age;

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (!(obj is MyDog other)) return false;
            return (this.Name == other.Name) && (this.Age == other.Age);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see what you are saying...but a small flaw is...where your `other` comes from...you just passed in `obj` right?

Comment: @Gen.L Actually, ```other``` is the result after ```obj``` converted to MyDog.

Comment: thank you sir~~~~~~~~~~~